# Ubuntu 16.04 - How to display hard disk details in computer like it does on Windows in My computer?

Tags: 16.04, disk, disk-usage, disk-management

In Windows, whenever I open "My Computer", the details come up of all drive partitions and the size details of each partition. Is it possible to get the similar information in Ubuntu 16.04, when I open the computer icon – complete details of hard disks as shown in Windows.
E. g.:

[image: Computer overview of Windows Explorer]

Comment: What exactly would you like to know or see?

Comment: Well i wanted it to show  up as it usually does in windows, i.e by clicking on my computer icon it shows up all the drives, names, size, used data etc. Was looking for same feature in ubuntu.

Comment: Is the *Places* side-bar of Nautilus not enough? It shows all known and supported file systems similar to Windows explorer. (Linux doesn't have the same concept of "drives" as Windows does; in fact Microsoft is trying to move away from their historical concept in favour of a more Unix-like file hierarchy). Also, could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Digging into the disk analyzer for each detail every time would be irritating. I was looking for something like getting all info in a single glance as I see on windows. Anyways, this should also suffice for now. Thankyou.

Comment: Until this question is reopened: I'm not sure what kind of visualization you imagine. If you want the numbers, I recommend the [`df`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/df.1.html) and [`lsblk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/lsblk.8.html) terminal commands.

Answer (score 1):

Menu -> Show Applications -> Disk Usage Analyzer and/or Disks should give what you want.

You can directly search for it by Power/Windows button and typing Disk. There are 2 utilities that comes by default in ubuntu : Disks and Disk Usage Analyzer. That is assuming you are using Desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

You should try installing **gparted**

```
sudo apt install gparted -y
```

Then go to Menu -> Gparted